# How to remove an action added by a child theme of Genesis

Tags: actions, genesis-theme-framework

I developed a child theme for Genesis that adds Bootstrap on top of it.

In the core of this child theme I edited the way the category is displayed in the post, putting it above the title.

Now, I'd like to remove the action again but it seems not working.

This is theory, below I write something more, with code.

**PRACTICALLY**

I have the file `src/lib/post.php` that [adds the action `shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories`](https://github.com/Aerendir/Genestrap/blob/master/src/lib/post.php#L28-L58):

```
function shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories() {

    $filtered = apply_filters( 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', '[post_categories]' );

    if ( false == trim( $filtered ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove the label and commas
    $filtered = str_replace([__( 'Filed Under: ', 'genesis' ), ', '], '', $filtered);

    genesis_markup( [
        'open'    => '<p %s>',
        'close'   => '</p>',
        'content' => genesis_strip_p_tags( $filtered ),
        'context' => 'entry-meta-categories',
    ] );
}
add_filter( 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', 'do_shortcode', 20 );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', 9 );
remove_action( 'genesis_after_post_content', 'genesis_post_meta' );
```

As you can see, I add my custom function `genesis_post_meta` and then I remove the Genesis action `genesis_post_meta`.

Now, from the file `src/functions.php` I'd like to remove the action `shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories` I added before:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', 9 );
```

But this doesn't work.

**WHY AM I DOING THIS**

The final goal is to provide a Bootstrap on top Genesis, so, the files in `src/lib` should not be modified: this way, when I update the main repository, it is possible to update the child theme.

To further customize the child theme, instead, I want to use the file `src/functions.php` that is never updated on the repository.

Doing this, if someday I update the file `src/lib/post.php` it is sufficient to copy the files from the main repository into the customized version of the theme and all the other customizations done through the `src/functions.php` file will continue to work.

But, as told, I'm not able to remove actions set by the files in `src/lib`.

**CONCLUSIONS AND QUESTION (AGAIN)**

I add the action `shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories` in `src/lib/post.php`.

Then I'd like to remove the action `shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories` from the file `src/functions.php` but this doesn't work:

```
// src/function.php

remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', 9 );
```

**How can I remove the action added in `src/lib/post.php` from the file `src/functions.php`?**

Comment: Are you removing the original action with the same priority level it was initially added with - and are you removing the original action *before* you are adding it back in?

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240929/how-to-remove-action-from-plugin) helpful?

Comment: D. Dan, I found that post on Google and tried to use it but didn't work. Now, I retrying and works. It was a problem of priority. I'm going to open a new question because I really don't understand how does priority works: I had to use priority 8 to remove an action added with priority 9, so added after I remove it o.O

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dan that commented with a useful post I found on Google but didn't read with the required attention, the solution is this:

```
function my_remove() {
    remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'shq_genestrap_post_meta_categories', 9 );
}
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'my_remove', 8);
```

Using priority `9` in `add_action()` doesn't work: I had to set a priority lower than the one used to add the action I'm going to remove.

Anyway, I don't understand why a lower priority works: it seems to be counterintuitive.

About this I opened another question: [I don't understand why I need a lower priority to remove an action with a higher priority to make it work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313605/i-dont-understand-why-i-need-a-lower-priority-to-remove-an-action-with-a-higher)

Anyone willing to reply is welcome!